# Casting enum variable to enum type

Tags: c, enums

I have encountered a code where `enum` variable is casted to `enum` type. I am unable to understand the use of such casting. For E. g.

```
typedef enum{x,y,z} en;

void main(){
  en const v;
  switch(v){
  case (en)y : {
    }
    break;
  case (en)x: {
    }
    break;
  default : {
    foo();
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

What is the use of casting `x` or `y` to `enum` type that is `(en)x` in case label?

Comment: I suggest that one should not do this as this can actually *hide* errors that would otherwise be found (with high compiler-warnings).

Comment: What error this can hide? Could you please explain??

Answer (score 3):

Such code is symptomatic of sheer paranoia, that's all. In fact, it's possibly harmful since in forcing a cast, you're hinting to the compiler that you know what you're doing so it may not warn you of an errant case label.

`switch`ing directly on an `enum` is perfectly valid, as `enum`s are essentially integral types. You can safely drop the `(en)` casts.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I was of the same opinion, but the question is if some has used it what is though behind or we say it is programmer mistake.  Also does C standard says something about the same.